# Audio SeekBar issue in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, volume, android-seekbar

```
package com.example.va_embedding

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.VideoView
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val venom = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.venomvideo)
        venom.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.venom)
        val mediaC = MediaController(this)
        mediaC.setAnchorView(venom)
        venom.setMediaController(mediaC)
        val vc = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar2)
        vc.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
            onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar2, Int: i, boolean : b)
            Log.i(:"Seekbar changed", i = Integer.toString())

        })

        venom.start()
    }
}
```

XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/venomvideo"
        android:layout_width="333dp"
        android:layout_height="568dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Objective: To get an Audio SeekBar in the app

Issue: I am getting an error saying Interface do not have constructors. I am also facing an issue when I am trying to add OnSeekBarChangeListener() method.

I am using Android Studio 3.6.1.

My SDK version is 28

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener is an interface not a class, you can not call the constructor SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener().

So instead use the below code:

```
vc.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
            @Override
            override fun onProgressChanged(
                seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int,
                fromUser: Boolean
            ){
            Log.i(:"Seekbar changed", i = Integer.toString())
           }
        })
```